# Setting the glyph image in a FireMonkey TListView

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a FireMonkey TListView in a project.  It's using a DynamicAppearance, each item features a couple of text entries and a glyph button.  What I cannot seem to figure out is how to set the glyph image for that button when I build the list.

For example, when building the list items, I can do this for a text field:

```
  lviAmount := lvi.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemText>('Amount');
  lviAmount.Text := FloatToStrF( tx.amount, ffNumber, 7, 2);
```

But I cannot see how to do the same thing with a TListItemGlyphButton:

```
  lviDelete := lvi.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemGlyphButton>('DeleteButton');
  //then??
```

How can I set/assign the glyph image on a TListItemGlyphButton in a FireMonkey TListView?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that with a TListViewGlyphButton. It's only for Add, Delete or CheckBox button types. If you want to have an image of your own, use TListItemImage, and use the Bitmap property, e.g:

```
lviDelete := lvi.Objects.FindObjectT<TListItemImage>('DeleteButton');    
lviDelete.Bitmap := SomeBitmap;
```

You'll also need to use the OnListViewItemClickEx event to determine whether or not it was the image that was clicked

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I think that will do the trick.  I tried setting it to Delete, but it just gave me a blank button.  Do you know what a TListItemGlyphButton is for then?